# RequireJS Optimization breaking module dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs, momentjs, r.js, angular-moment

So I am trying to compile all my javascript modules into one file using the r.js from RequireJS. While the code remain in separate files, the scripts run just fine. But after r.js has put them all in the same file, momentTimezones does not seem to get loaded.
The module angularMoment uses them both and only moment gets loaded.

Here is the shim I am using the my main.js:

```
shim: {
    angular: {
        exports: 'angular' 
    },
    uiRouter: ['angular'],
    ngResource: ['angular'],
    ngAnimate: ['angular'],
    angularLocaleSweden: ['angular'],
    angularMoment:{
        deps: ['angular', 'momentTimezones', 'moment'],
        exports: 'angularMoment'
    },
    uiModal: ['angular'],
    angularConfirm: ['uiModal'],
    lodash: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    jquery: {
        exports: '$'
    },
    angularToastr: ['jquery', 'angular'],
    'jquery.signalr': ['jquery'],
    'signalr.hubs': ['jquery.signalr'],
    'ng-file-upload': ['angular'],
    'ng-file-upload-shim': ['angular'],
    'ng-img-crop': ['angular']
}
```

and this is my r.js build configuration:

```
({
    baseUrl: './Client',
    mainConfigFile: './Client/main.js',
    name: 'main',
    out: './Client/main.min.js',
    //wrapShim: true,
    optimize: 'none',
    //findNestedDepencies: true
})
```

When I try to run my compiled main.js I get:

```
TypeError: moment.utc(...).tz is not a function
```

and

```
angular-moment: named timezone specified but moment.tz() is undefined. Did you forget to include moment-timezone.js?
```

Everything else works.
I've looked through the compiled main.js and the content of moment-timezones is in there, after the content of moment.js and before the content of angularMoment.js

Comment: Well I got it to work..
The error occurred in modules which used the .tz method call from the moment-timezones library. What I did was add this library as a dependency in the call to define in modules needing it. And that did the trick, but I have no idea what so ever as to why the code works without the module dependency before it is optimized by r.js and why I need to define the the module dependency for the optimized code.